# How to achieve interface null vs throw dispatch in pure Kotlin without Java

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, kotlin-null-safety

Consider this example:

---

**CommonHandler.java**:

Common handler with additional logic. Here it's very simplified:

```java
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0;

public class CommonHandler {

  private void doCoolStuffBefore() { /* do some cool stuff */ }
  private void doCoolStuffAfter() { /* do some cool stuff */ }

  public <R> R getResult(Function0<R> provider) {
    R result;
    doCoolStuffBefore();
    try {
      result = provider.invoke();
    } finally {
      doCoolStuffAfter();
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

---

**NullableHandler.kt**:

Handler version that returns `null` if operation throws exception. The result is of the type `R?`

```
class NullableHandler : CommonHandler() {
  override fun <R> getResult(provider: Function0<R>): R? {
    return try {
      super.getResult(provider)
    } catch(ex: Throwable) {
      null
    }
  }
}
```

---

**ThrowingHandler.kt**:

Handler version that wraps errors in it's internal exception type. The result type is `R`.

```
class ThrowingHandler : CommonHandler() {

  class WrappedException(message: String, cause: Throwable?): Exception(message, cause)

  override fun <R> getResult(provider: Function0<R>): R {
    return try {
      super.getResult(provider)
    } catch(ex: Throwable) {
      throw WrappedException("Throwing handler failed with exception: ${ex.javaClass.name}", ex)
    }
  }

}
```

---

**Api.kt**:

Basically any API we do not own and cannot modify.

```
object Api {

  fun find(query: String): Int =
      if (query.length > 3) 42
      else throw NoSuchElementException("Not found for $query")

  fun select(query: String): String =
      if (query.count { it == 'x' } > 2) "Selected"
      else throw NoSuchElementException("Not found for $query")

}
```

---

Now, having all the above classes, we can implement API wrapper:

```
object ApiProxy {

  private val throwingHandler = ThrowingHandler()
  private val nullableHandler = NullableHandler()

  fun find(query: String): Int = throwingHandler.getResult { Api.find(query) }
  fun findOrNull(query: String): Int? = nullableHandler.getResult { Api.find(query) }

  fun select(query: String): String = throwingHandler.getResult { Api.select(query) }
  fun selectOrNull(query: String): String? = nullableHandler.getResult { Api.select(query) }

}
```

---

My question is, how can I implement similar hierarchy **without falling back to Java**, such that there is single class/interface with method that can return either `R` type or `R?` type. As far as I know, we cannot declare explicitly platform types in Kotlin with `R!` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simple solution would be to make the getResult from the CommonHandler return nullable results and then handle the null return as it was an exception. At least that's what came in to my mind at first.

so, following the hint we'll have the common handler defined as

```
open class CommonHandler {
    private fun doCoolStuffBefore() { /* do some cool stuff */
    }

    private fun doCoolStuffAfter() { /* do some cool stuff */
    }

    open fun <R> getResult(provider: Function0<R>): R? {
        doCoolStuffBefore()
        return try {
            provider.invoke()
        } finally {
            doCoolStuffAfter()
        }
    }
}
```

the NullableHandler doesn't change but it does the ThrowingHandler

```
class ThrowingHandler : CommonHandler() {

    class WrappedException(message: String, cause: Throwable?): Exception(message, cause)

    override fun <R> getResult(provider: Function0<R>): R {
        return try {
            super.getResult(provider) ?: throw AnotherWrappedException("whooops")
        } catch(ex: Throwable) {
            throw WrappedException("Throwing handler failed with exception: ${ex.javaClass.name}", ex)
        }
    }

}
```

where you use the elvis operator to return the value if it's not null or throwing `AnotherWrappedException("whooops")` if there is a null value.

What do you think? Could it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the return type as nullable R:

```kotlin
open class CommonHandler {
    private fun doCoolStuffBefore() { /* do some cool stuff */
    }

    private fun doCoolStuffAfter() { /* do some cool stuff */
    }

    open fun <R> getResult(provider: () -> R): R? {
        doCoolStuffBefore()
        return try {
            provider.invoke()
        } finally {
            doCoolStuffAfter()
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can narrow the scope to a non-nullable R in the subclass.

```kotlin
class ThrowingHandler : CommonHandler() {

    class WrappedException(message: String, cause: Throwable?): Exception(message, cause)

    override fun <R> getResult(provider: () -> R): R {
        return try {
            super.getResult(provider)!!
        } catch(ex: Throwable) {
            throw WrappedException("Throwing handler failed with exception: ${ex.javaClass.name}", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

Your ThrowableHandler is assuming a null cannot be returned by the API, so it's perfectly reasonable to use the `!!` operator here and let any KotlinNPE get wrapped in your WrappedException. This is actually better than what you already have because the unexpected exception is contained in your wrapper rather than bubbling out to a Java NPE elsewhere in your code. If you need to wrap an API that is supposed to be able to return null, then I think you also need a NullableThrowingHandler.

Comment: Yeah, the API I'm working with never returns null (exception is thrown instead). Cool stuff about overriding return type as non-nullable. I didn't know that or failed to remember :)